# Default value is not showing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

```
Rails 3.2
```

I am using Slim for my application. In one of my views, I have the following:

```
    .form-horizontal-column
      .form-group
        = label_tag :paid_at
        = text_field_tag :paid_at, :value => DateTime.now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"), class: "date-picker-past"
```

But, instead of seeing a default value, like 02/07/2019, I am seeing this instead:

{:value=>"02/07/2019", :class=>"date-picker-past"}

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails 3.2. Use it this way instead:

```
= text_field_tag :paid_at, DateTime.now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"), class: "date-picker-past"
```

basically remove `:value =>`

Comment: That's how I had, but the problem is that I could not change the default value when the form is displayed

Comment: I don't get this, what are you trying to say ?. What I posted will set a value in the `paid_at` field. Do you want a placeholder value instead ?, the one that's used a example and is grayed out ?

Comment: I am trying to have a default value that can be changed, and if that can't happen, a placeholder value

Comment: I don't know why setting a value the form won't let you change it, that really depends on how you're building your form, something must be preventing your field from being updated. A HTML field can have a value and can be changed, that's something basic. If you want to try with a placeholder value then change it to `= text_field_tag :paid_at, nil, placeholder: DateTime.now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"), class: "date-picker-past"`